# How to include an up-level reference in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I'm new to Bazel (version 0.28.1). 
How do you include a header file in another directory?  The directory structure below is a representation of my problem.

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
├── src
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── hellomake.c
│   ├── hellofunc.c
│   └── BUILD
└── include
    └── hellomake.h
```

The tree builds fine with the Makefile in src.  However, using Make I'm able to reference the include file with "-I ../include".  When I try to build the same tree with Bazel I am unable to successfully include the header file hellomake.h. Obviously, an up-level references, '..', does not work.

My BUILD file:

```
cc_library (
    name = "hellomake",
    srcs = ["hellomake.c"],
    hdrs = ["//include/hellomake.h"],
    copts = ["-I include"],
)

cc_library (
    name = "hellofunc",
    srcs = ["hellofunc.c"],
    hdrs = ["//include/hellomake.h"],
    copts = ["-I include"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    deps = [ ":hellomake", ":hellofunc", ],
)
```

From '.' my command is:

```
bazel build //src/hello
```

Answer (score 6):

Direct answer would be, you cannot just reach across package boundaries. Package is each node in workspace directory tree that has its `BUILD` file, so the minimal change would be to make your tree with sources and headers one package (move `BUILD` up by one directory) and heave it read like this instead:

```
cc_library (
    name = "hellomake",
    srcs = ["src/hellomake.c"],
    hdrs = ["include/hellomake.h"],
    copts = ["-I include"],
)

cc_library (
    name = "hellofunc",
    srcs = ["src/hellofunc.c"],
    hdrs = ["include/hellomake.h"],
    copts = ["-I include"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello",
    deps = [ ":hellomake", ":hellofunc", ],
)
```

You could then build:

```
bazel build //:hello
```

But I suspect there is a bit more to unpack here. Based on linking order (`deps`) of `cc_binary` rule, I suspect `hellomake.c` actually isn't as much a library, but a source of your binary with it's own `main()` and hence:

- it could be directly declared as such
- and `hellomake.h` is actually interface of `hellofunc.c` and should be named accordingly

Based on that assumption, the `BUILD` file would now look like this:

```
cc_library (
    name = "hellofunc",
    srcs = ["src/hellofunc.c"],
    hdrs = ["include/hellofunc.h"],
    includes = ["include"],
)

cc_binary (
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["src/hellomake.c"],
    deps = [":hellofunc"],
)
```

Now if you actually wanted to use sources and headers as separate packages, you could do that, but you'd have to declare the header file(s) as a `cc_library` in `//include` package by putting this in `./include/BUILD`:

```
cc_library (
    name = "hellofunc_hdr",
    hdrs = ["hellofunc.h"],
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//src:__pkg__"],
)
```

And then in `//src` (`./src/BUILD`) you could say:

```
cc_library (
    name = "hellofunc",
    srcs = ["hellofunc.c"],
    deps = ["//include:hellofunc_hdr"],
)

cc_binary (
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hellomake.c"],
    deps = [":hellofunc"],
)
```

With that you could run `bazel build //src:hello`.

Admittedly, this looks a bit odd and such packaging does not seem to convey much meaningful structure, so perhaps we could end up having a hellofunc (library) as one (`func`) package and hellomake as source for our binary as another (`hello`). The tree would look like this:

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
├── func
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── hellofunc.c
│   └── hellofunc.h
└── hello
    ├── BUILD
    └── hellomake.c
```

And the `BUILD` file in `./func/` could be:

```
cc_library (
    name = "func",
    srcs = ["hellofunc.c"],
    hdrs = ["hellofunc.h"],
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//hello:__pkg__"],
)
```

With the in `./hello/`:

```
cc_binary (
    name = "hello",
    srcs = ["hellomake.c"],
    deps = ["//func"],
)
```

We could then run `build bazel //hello`